# Use of spnego and kerberos with gss in graal

Tags: java, quarkus, graalvm, spnego, jgss

I'm attempting to reuse some existing code which enables spnego authentication in a new Quarkus app. The Quarkus app when compiled as a standard JAR and run with OpenJDK 11 works perfectly. As soon as a I package it up as a native executable (on linux) I get the following exception:

```
2021-05-21 17:31:17,178 ERROR [com.organisation.sec.ker.eng.gss.AbstractGssAuthenticator] (executor-thread-1) GSS error occured: GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Invalid argument (400) - Cannot find key of appropriate type to decrypt AP-REQ - RC4 with HMAC)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.acceptSecContext(Krb5Context.java:859)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:361)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:303)
    at sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.GSS_acceptSecContext(SpNegoContext.java:905)
    at sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext(SpNegoContext.java:556)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:361)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:303)
    at com.organisation.security.kerberos.engine.gss.AbstractGssAuthenticator$AuthAction.run(AbstractGssAuthenticator.java:110)
    at com.organisation.security.kerberos.engine.gss.AbstractGssAuthenticator$AuthAction.run(AbstractGssAuthenticator.java:77)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:147)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:423)
    at com.organisation.security.kerberos.engine.gss.AbstractGssAuthenticator.handle(AbstractGssAuthenticator.java:49)
    at com.organisation.security.kerberos.KerberosAuthenticationFilter.processAuthHeader(KerberosAuthenticationFilter.java:95)
    at com.organisation.security.kerberos.KerberosAuthenticationFilter.authenticate(KerberosAuthenticationFilter.java:64)
    at com.organisation.jaxrs.security.AuthenticationContainerRequestFilter.filter(AuthenticationContainerRequestFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:312)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:249)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.ResteasyFilter$ResteasyResponseWrapper.service(ResteasyFilter.java:70)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.ResteasyFilter$ResteasyResponseWrapper.sendError(ResteasyFilter.java:76)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:172)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:503)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.ResteasyFilter.doFilter(ResteasyFilter.java:31)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:63)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:65)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:56)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:111)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:108)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.UndertowDeploymentRecorder$9$1.call(UndertowDeploymentRecorder.java:587)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:152)
    at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.UndertowDeploymentRecorder$1.handleRequest(UndertowDeploymentRecorder.java:119)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:290)
    at io.undertow.server.DefaultExchangeHandler.handle(DefaultExchangeHandler.java:18)
    at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.UndertowDeploymentRecorder$5$1.run(UndertowDeploymentRecorder.java:413)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2415)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:519)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixJavaThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixJavaThreads.java:192)
Caused by: KrbException: Invalid argument (400) - Cannot find key of appropriate type to decrypt AP-REQ - RC4 with HMAC
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.authenticate(KrbApReq.java:278)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.<init>(KrbApReq.java:149)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.InitSecContextToken.<init>(InitSecContextToken.java:139)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.acceptSecContext(Krb5Context.java:832)
    ... 67 more
```

I'm fairly new to Graal, and not sure what I need to add to allow this to work (or if it is even something that is currently supported).

I did have some problems to start with nad I've enabled reflection for `sun.security.provider.ConfigFile`, `sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl`, `sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl` which sorted them out, unfortunatly I'm not sure how to deal with the missing key type.

Here's an example of the code

```
    final GSSManager manager = GSSManager.getInstance();
    final Oid spnegoOid = new Oid(oid);
    final GSSCredential serverCreds = manager.createCredential(null, GSSCredential.DEFAULT_LIFETIME, spnegoOid,
            GSSCredential.ACCEPT_ONLY);

    final GSSContext context = manager.createContext(serverCreds);

    try
    {
        final byte[] outToken = context.acceptSecContext(inToken, 0, inToken.length);
```

Comment: The error message is about a legacy crypto algorithm (RC4) which is -- unfortunately -- still the default for Active Directory. But not enabled by Graal apparently. Try to tweak your `/etc/krb5.conf` to remove RC4 from the list of algos that is used for negotiation -- assuming your KDC supports something better e.g. AES256.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter yes that does seem to be the problem. I tried AES256 but then got an error about it not being supported by the KDC so I will need to see if active directory supports any encryption that is also supported by graal.

Comment: Or, try to tweak `/etc/krb5.conf` to explicitly enable RC4 client-side.

Comment: Cf. https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-devel/doc/admin/enctypes.html

Answer (score 1):

What Java version is running on linux? If it is Java 17 or above, this might be the problem:
[JDK 17 Security Enhancements](https://seanjmullan.org/blog/2021/09/14/jdk17):

**Kerberos**

- **Deprecate 3DES and RC4 in Kerberos**

  3DES and RC4 Kerberos encryption types have now been disabled by
  default. Both 3DES and RC4 are weak encryption algorithms that should
  not be used. The Kerberos 3DES and RC4 encryption types are
  officially deprecated in RFC 8429.

  By default the des3-hmac-sha1 and rc4-hmac encryption types are now
  disabled, but can be re-enabled, at your own risk, by setting the
  allow_weak_crypto property to true in the krb5.conf configuration
  file. However, note that will also re-enable other weak encryption
  types that are already disabled such as des-cbc-crc and des-cbc-md5.
  Alternatively, set the default_tkt_enctypes, default_tgs_enctypes,
  and permitted_enctypes properties to the encryption types that are
  allowed.

  Issue: [JDK-8139348](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8139348)

Make sure to check the following options for your kerberos-service user (the one used for generating the keytab file):

[image]

Afterwards run `klist purge` on your machine and logout/logon the current user.

Alternative you could add the following to your *krb5.conf* file (as a workaround, not recommended):

```
[libdefaults]
allow_weak_crypto=true
```

Also you could generate a new keytab file using `/crypto ALL` with the `ktpass` command:

```
ktpass /out "server.keytab" /crypto ALL /princ HTTP/server@REALM /mapuser KERBEROS_SERVICEUSER /pass PASSWORD /ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL
```

Replace `HTTP/server@REALM`, `KERBEROS_SERVICEUSER` and `PASSWORD` with according values.